# Comments split by page break

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to comment the top of a table that takes up an entire page but the last two columns always have their comments split in half or on the next page. Is there a way to have vba move the comments that are close to the edge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try setting the print area of the worksheet to include the area that the comments occupy.